# execute query after call mysql stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have some problem with store procedures in mysql.
This is my store procedure code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `projects_grid`(in pagination varchar(100))
BEGIN
DECLARE a,b INT;
declare percent float;
DECLARE cur_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM tbl_projects;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET b = 1;
drop temporary  table IF EXISTS tbl_temp ;
create Temporary table tbl_temp(id int,name varchar(100) charset utf8,project_name varchar(100) charset utf8,project_type varchar(100) charset utf8,start_date int,end_date int,percent varchar(5));
OPEN cur_1;
REPEAT
FETCH cur_1 INTO a;
set @name='';
set @project_type='';
set @project_name='';
set @b_date='';
set @e_date='';
set @percent='';
set @e_id='';
set @p_id='';
set @completed_rows_count=0;
set @rows_count=0;
select project, (select name from tbl_client where id=tbl_projects.employer_id) as name,(select name from tbl_project_type where id=tbl_projects.project_type_id) as project_name,contract_begin_date,contract_terminate_date into @project_name,@name,@project_type,@b_date,@e_date from tbl_projects where id=a;
SELECT count(PS.status) into @completed_rows_count FROM  tbl_projects_status AS PS JOIN tbl_projects_results AS S ON PS.projects_results_id = S.id where project_id=a and PS.status='1';
SELECT count(PS.status) into @rows_count FROM tbl_projects_status AS PS JOIN tbl_projects_results AS S ON PS.projects_results_id = S.id where project_id=a;
set percent=(@completed_rows_count/@rows_count)*100;
insert into tbl_temp values(a,@project_name,@name,@project_type,@b_date,@e_date,concat(percent,'%'));
UNTIL b = 1
END REPEAT;
CLOSE cur_1;
set @pagination=pagination;
set @query=concat('SELECT distinct(id),name,project_name,project_type,start_date,end_date,percent FROM tbl_temp ',@pagination);
PREPARE stmp FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmp;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmp;
END
```

And this is my php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'bootstrap.php';
$query="call projects_grid('')";
$result=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
foreach($result as $record)
{
    echo $record;
}
$query="select count(*) from tbl_projects";
$result=mysql_query($query); // Boolean false given :(
$result=mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $result[0];
?>
```

When I execute query after the procedure, at the debug mode, system shows me given boolean as false!.
How can I execute query after call stored procedure?

Comment: Is this because you do not have permission to fire `select` on that table. Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found answer:
Use mysqli instead mysql.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('your_hostname','your_username' ,'your_password','your_db_name');
$result=$mysqli->query($query);
$result->data_seek(0);
```

After execute your query you must use this commands:

```
mysqli_free_result();
mysqli_next_result($mysqli);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

We can find a usage example for the `mysql_query()` function in its [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#example-1662):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

To sum up:

1. `mysql_query()` returns `false` when the query failed
2. `mysql_error()` returns the error message

<sub>P.S. You can also see the *"This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future"* warning but I suppose you already know that.</sub>

**Edit:** The *"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"* error message can normally be fixed by freeing the previous result set with [mysql_free_result()](http://php.net/mysql_free_result). It's not that there's necessarily something wrong in your stored procedure—the legacy mysql extension was not really designed with stored routines in mind.

Comment: my query work correctly when I dont use store procedure. Also it work on phpmyAdmin.

Comment: In that case you don't need to read the error message. Guessing is way more fun!

Comment: Error: Invalid query: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: some one **HELP** me pls :-(

Comment: Finally I found the answer: